# In web.py, How to 301 redirect to another domain?

Tags: python, http, web, web.py

Function seeother() and redirect() in web.py is no use. I try to use
    `web.header('Location', 'www.google.com')`
    `web.header('status', '301')`
or
    `web.HTTPError('301', {'Location': 'www.google.com'})`
but still redirect to:
    `http://127.0.0.1:80/www.google.com`
which is not what we want:
    `http://google.com`
How to redirect correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
web.HTTPError('301', {'Location': 'http://www.google.com'})
```

Note that you must put `http://` to denote an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

> which is not what we want:
>   `http://google.com`

So why do you then redirect to `www.google.com` instead of `http://google.com`?